# pushing to list results in one item always being left out

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to take an object, upload a file in the object, get the downloaded url and add it to the the object, the problem is whenever I try to push the new data to an array, I always end up missing one of the items and I can't tell why this is happening.

My code:

```
const transformedData = async () => {
  const urlList = [];
  for await (let dog of data.dogs) {
    // console.log(dog);
    if (dog.file.length === 0 || dog.file === undefined) {
     
      urlList.push({ ...dog, akcPapersUrl: "" });
    } else {
      
      const uploadTask = await storageRef
        .child(`dog/${dog.akcNumber}/${dog.file[0].name}`)
        .put(dog.file[0]);

      uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL().then((res) => {
        urlList.push({ ...dog, akcPapersUrl: res });
      });
    }
  }
  console.log(urlList);
  return urlList;
};

await transformedData()
  .then((res) => {
    data = { ...data, transformed: res };
    return data;
  })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    sendRegistration(res);
  });
```

Comment: I don't think this solves your whole problem, but this is wrong: `dog.file.length === 0 || dog.file === undefined`. That test is backward. `dog.file.length` can fail with an exception before you have a chance to check `dog.file === undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an `await` for the `getDownloadURL` call, so the loop does not wait for that Promise to finish. Use:

```
const uploadTask = await storageRef
.child(`dog/${dog.akcNumber}/${dog.file[0].name}`)
.put(dog.file[0]);

const akcPapersUrl = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
urlList.push({ ...dog, akcPapersUrl });
```

It only *just happens* to only miss the final one because you have *another* `await` before this inside the loop (which is enough time for the prior `getDownloadURL` to resolve, presumably)